# Lightning network: which update messages are replayed?

Tags: lightning-network

If I understand correctly, after a new node connects to a peer in the Lightning network, it receives all past channel announcement / update messages for currently open channels to recreate a local snapshot of the network. What messages are replayed? For example, for a very old channel with lots of channel updates, are all of them replayed? Why not just report the latest update message?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [BOLT 07 which describes the gossip protocol](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md) and depends on [BOLT 08](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/08-transport.md) (Transport via the Noise Protocol framework) and [BOLT 01](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/01-messaging.md) (Messaging)

In particular if you look at the `channel_update message` you will find this quote from the BOLT 07:

> if timestamp is NOT greater than that of the last-received channel_update for this `short_channel_id` AND for `node_id`:
>   SHOULD ignore the message.
>
> otherwise:
>   if the timestamp is equal to the last-received `channel_update` AND the fields (other than signature) differ:
>   MAY blacklist this node_id.
>   MAY forget all channels associated with it.
>
> if the timestamp is unreasonably far in the future:
>   MAY discard the channel_updat

Also in the section about rebroadcasting you can find the following quotes:

> upon receiving a new `channel_announcement` or a `channel_update` or `node_announcement` with an updated timestamp:
>   SHOULD update its local view of the network's topology accordingly.
>
> after applying the changes from the announcement:
>
> [...]
>
> SHOULD update the appropriate metadata AND store the signature associated with the announcement.
>   Note: this will later allow the node to rebuild the announcement for its peers.

The way how I read this is that nodes only store the latest `channel_update message` per channel which they can detect via the timestamp. Also when the initial sync takes place the latest update messages for each channel are also being sent.

Comment: This looks like a pattern: I ask a question, you cite a BOLT and explain it to me :) With all due respect, BOLT's language is not easy to grasp... So, after A joins and connects to B, B sends to A all _latest_ updates for all channels B thinks are live? Does A even have to ask for this a-la GETADDR - ADDR in Bitcoin?